# NodeJS express can't receive POST json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm trying to send a JSON to my NodeJS route.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"homer"}' http://localhost:3000/api
```

So, in my server.js:

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended:true}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
...
```

Then, in my route:

```
router.post('/api', function (req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

So, the output shows `undefined`

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using Express v4.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some middleware before the `bodyParser` middlewares that is reading request data?

Comment: @mscdex you got it. solved by using `router` AFTER `bodyparser`. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middleware and routes in Express 4 are executed in the order they're added to your app. So you need to make sure that your routes come after your `bodyParser` middlewares are used.

Answer (score 0):

JSON stringify makes a string from object.
Use

```
 JSON.parse({"name":"homer"})
```

or

```
 $.param({"name":"homer"})
```

Comment: same `undefined` problem. I guess it is something with `body-parser`, because I'm trying using `curl` and shows same error

Comment: try to remove your contentType in the ajax post

Comment: same error. I'm sure is something with back-end. I'm using this curl to test: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"homer"}' http://localhost:3000/api` and not works

Comment: solved by using `router` AFTER `body-parser`. thank you!